# telescoping series question?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Are all telescoping series absolutely convergent? if not, is there an example of a telescoping series that is not absolutely convergent?

Answer (score 1):

Try $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left( \frac{(-1)^n}{n} - \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n-1}\right).$$ It clearly converges (it is by definition a telescoping series), but 
$$
\left\lvert \frac{(-1)^n}{n} - \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n-1} \right\rvert = 
\left\lvert \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-1} \right\rvert > \frac{2}{n}.
$$

Comment: why did you add 1/n-1 on the right hand side of the equality? if all (-) turned to (+) wouldnt you also change n-1 to n+1?

Comment: No: write $$
\left\lvert \frac{(-1)^n}{n} - \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n-1} \right\rvert = \left\lvert (-1)^n\left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{-1}{n-1}\right) \right\rvert= \lvert (-1)^n\rvert\left\lvert \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-1} \right\rvert= \left\lvert \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-1} \right\rvert
$$
In other terms, the $(-1)^n$ is factored out and "eaten" by the absolute values.

Comment: how do you know (-1)^n * (-1) = (-1)^n-1?

Comment: also, does it change if the series is strictly (s_n- s_(n+1))?

Comment: Because $(-1)^{n-1} =(-1)^{n-1}\cdot 1 = (-1)^{n-1}\cdot (-1)^2 = (-1)^{n}\cdot(-1) .$ I don't understand your last comment, howver: "strictly what?"

Comment: if your series is ∑sn-sn+1 instead of ∑sn-(sn-1) does it change? The telescoping series example that you gave was ∑sn-(sn-1).

Comment: It is the same: consider 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(  \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n-1} - \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)$$ instead.

Comment: I dont think the sequence sn= (-1)^(n-1)/(n-1)  converges though?

Comment: It does, to 0.  It's the same as $(-1)^ n/n$.